# dell studio slim 540 not installing ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, command-line

i offered to install ubuntu on my uncles computer because windows is failing,the computer has the specs of a intel 2 quad processor,15 gigs of ram and 1 terabyte of hdd,i loaded the OS through flashdrive and hit install,after a few seconds,it was installing and then shortly after it said that the installation has a bug and or is corrupted then says the computer might have a faulty hard drive or disk drive,then i went to see if i could just install the OS through the wubi.exe and i couldnt because linux erased the whole harddrive,i dont have windows anymore,and it wont install linux,is there any possible way around this? :"(

Comment: sorry its a dell studio 540

Comment: is the pendrive bootable? try booting from it (dell has a shortcut key for chosing default boot device most probably its f12, press f12 at startup and chose the pendrive from the list or change the boot order from the bios).  and select Install Ubuntu. and if the device is not bootable, try making a bootable one from any other computer (use unetbooting for linux, lili for windows)

Comment: it says "ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. do you want to try running this step again before continuing? if you do not,your installation may fail or may be broken"

Answer (score 0):

If you have another system or Operating System use the Ubuntu ISO and Unetbootin and use a pen drive to install Ubuntu

Step 1: Download UNetbootin

Grab the UNetbootin executable. Download for  (Windows version or Linux version what ever applicable for you) and save it on your desktop.

Step 2: Execute UNetbootin and Create your own portable Linux distribution

After installing UNetbootin, insert the USB flash drive into an empty USB port of your PC. (Note: This is important, because if you insert it after you’ve opened the UNetbootin application, you will not be able to use the USB stick.).

Now, double-click on the UNetbootin executable, to launch the UNetbootin application.

all you have to do now is to select your favorite Linux distribution ISO image file which you have already downloaded, double-check if the USB drive selected is the one which you want to make bootable and click on OK.

If you have not already downloaded a Linux distribution, then UNetbootin can download it for you and then go ahead with the process of creating the bootable USB stick. All you have to do is select the preferred distribution and then the version/edition, and click on OK to begin the process.

That’s it! After the process completes, reboot your machine and boot from the USB stick.

Comment: it says "ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. do you want to try running this step again before continuing? if you do not,your installation may fail or may be broken"

Comment: the pendrive is bootable,it just doesnt work when i try ubuntu before installing,and when i goto install,it just wiped the whole hard drive and wont install giving me the error message i commented above

Comment: new error message: the installer encountered an unrecoverable error. a desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again